# Can the gerondif express a conditional

Tags: grammaire

This is from *La grande grammaire du français* edited by Anne Abeillé, it says:

> Son [le gerondif] sujet est le plus souvent non exprimé, mais peut l’être dans une subordonnée participiale, interprétée comme une circonstancielle.

> Paul arrivant à 20 heures, nous avons le temps.

Does this mean that the above means:

> Si Paul arrive à 20 heures, nous avons le temps.

Comment: The GGF (Anne Abeillé et Danièle Godard) do **not** say that *arrivant* is a *gérondif* in this sentence and even in very "traditional" prescriptive   grammar it would not be a *gérondif* because it is not preceded by *en*.

Comment: Le sens ici est _comme Paul arrive à 20 heures, nous avons le temps_.

Answer (score 8):

No, the participe présent cannot express a conditional subordinate and you could not rephrase the sentence using *si*. In order to replace the participial subordinate by a circumstantial subordinate you'd have to use *parce que*.

> Paul arrivant à 20 heures, nous avons le temps.

is an example sentence in the  paragraph *Le mode participe présent* (II-1.1.3.1) of the GGF that starts by stating that:

> Le participe présent est une forme invariable du verbe. Il est souvent appelé *gérondif* quand il est introduit par la préposition *en* mais il n'y a pas lieu d'avoir deux formes verbales distinctes<sup>1</sup> [...] Son sujet est le plus souvent non exprimé mais peut l’être dans une subordonnée participiale, interprétée comme une circonstancielle.

When the authors write "***son** sujet*", it is clear they mean the subject of the  *participe présent*. They give three examples of *participes présents*, two use "*en*+participe présent", and the third one is your sentence where *arrivant* is not preceded by *en*.

In a previous chapter (I-3.3.4.2) we can read:

> Les phrases au participe présent sont des subordonnées circonstancielles de temps (*[L'hiver approchant] il faut rentrer les cactus*<sup>2</sup>) ou de cause (*La discussion n'a pas pu aboutir, [Paul ayant refusé de prendre part au vote*] parfois appelées *participiales*.
> [...]
> Quand le participe présent est introduit par *en* il est parfois appelé gérondif et ne comporte pas de sujet. Il ne donne pas lieu à une phrase subordonnée mais à un syntagme verbal.

In the paragraph on "*l'interprétation de la subordonnée circonstancielle participiale*" (XI-7.2.1):

> La subordonnée participiale reçoit en général une interprétation de cause, qu'elle soit en début ou en fin de phrase. Le participe présent décrit le plus souvent une situation concomitante  avec celle du verbe principal, ou un aspect de celle-ci, et la relation de cause, permet de construire une situation plus large, englobant le deux situations.

And that is precisely the situation we have in the sentence:

> Paul arrivant à 20 heures, nous avons le temps.
> Nous avons le temps **parce que** Paul arrive à 20 heures.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The authors explain why they do not want to use the word *gérondif* in XI-7.2.1:</sup>

> <sup>Nous ne retenons pas le *terme* gérondif pour désigner la forme *en*+participe présent. En effet ce terme est trompeur car il fait croire que les formes avec et sans préposition seraient différentes, dérivées l'une du participe présent, et l'autre du gérondif latin, ce qui n'est pas le cas.
>
> (Suit une explication historique).</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I'm much inclined to say that here cause is also expressed.</sup>

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that.  Very nice elaboration.

Comment: _Parce que_ ou _comme_: _comme Paul arrive à 20 heures, nous avons le temps_ passe très bien.

Comment: @Frank *Puisque Paul arrive à 20 h, on a le temps*.

Comment: @jlliagre Tu objectes à _comme_? Ou tu proposes _puisque_ comme une alternative? _Comme_ me semble tout à fait possible ici.

Comment: @Frank Oui, bien sûr. *Parce que*, *comme* et *puisque* sont tous possibles. Il n'y a de toute façon pas de contexte pour en privilégier un.

Comment: Autre possibilité : *Etant donné que Paul arrive à 20 heures, ...*